# Why can't I use a FloatingActionButton in Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am very new to Android Development, but can I ask why the FAB is not supported in Activity and only in `AppCompactActivity`. Correct me if I am wrong but it's my understanding that as long as you are not bothered with backwards compatibility then using Activity is the one to use as you can directly implement material themes and use the latest material design like `CardView`s `RecyclerView`s and other layouts like `CoordinatorLayout`. Why then when you want to use a material design feature like the FAB does it force you to use the `AppCompactActivity`, I thought using the one supporting higher APIs would work. Am I missing something here, I know there are third party libs I can use, but I really need to get my head around this...

Comment: `Why then when you want to use a material design feature like the FAB?` Because you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`FloatingActionButton`**  is not a part of core android library. Rather it is a part of android support design library.

```
compile "com.android.support:design:27.0.2"
```

This means this class is not pre-installed in android devices. Also to use it, your activity must use one of the `AppCompat` themes. Hence you need to use `appcompat` library to use a default FAB.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
```

However, you can find many open source third party libraries for FAB in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can I ask, is the major push in terms of Android Development to use Material Design Principles, which the FAB is a part of? So when then if I wanted to create an app to take full advantage of all the latest Material Design Principle widgets and views and layouts and supports 21+ devices can I not use the FAB in Activity? I am still learning Android Development, so I am sorry if this is like a really stupid point I am pushing, but I just don't get it

Comment: I am not quite sure why they decided not to include design components in the core library. But still they developed the design support library and appcompat library which you can use to provide material design in both latest and older android versions. The only downside of appcompat library is that it adds around 1MB to your apk size, so not a big deal though.

Comment: So if I create an app using AppCompactActivity and the Design Support library is there anything that I won't be able to create (as in is there anything that I can create I'm Activity that I can't in AppCompactActivity?) How do I apply a complete app material theme using AppCompactActivity?

Comment: As `AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`, you can use all the features of `Activity` using `AppCompatActivity`.